# How to count the columns of a MySQL query when the number of columns returned is dynamic?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to retrieve the count of the number of columns a query returns? This can be easily done with a bound scripting language such as php, but I'm looking for db only solution.

Example:

```
CountCols(SELECT 'a','b','c')
    => 3
CountCols(SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables)
    => 2
```

Comment: Out of curiosity -- what is this useful for? I can't think of a situation when I've needed to know how many columns a query returns, except in a programming context where I was doing something fairly generic/abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
select 
    count(*)
from
    `information_schema`.`columns`
where
    `table_schema` = 'my_table_schema' and `table_name` = 'my_table_name';
```

You only need to use `table_schema` if the table name exists in more than one database.

---

Based on your response comment, you are looking to count a dynamic number of columns.  You may be able to do this with a temporary table, but you cannot access the data of a temporary table without possibly [installing a patch](http://venublog.com/2010/02/03/show-temporary-tables).

Of note, there is [a similar outstanding SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443672/list-of-temporary-table-columns-mysql) asking how to select columns from a temporary table.

Comment: That would be the idea, but I'm more looking for something generic. The problem is that I need to know number of columns of arbitrary results (as in example). Those are not stored in the info schema.

Comment: Select them into a view or temporary table, and then access the information_schema?  We can search for some patches that do this.

Comment: Here is a person who has a patch to add access to temporary tables: http://venublog.com/2010/02/03/show-temporary-tables/ ; Meanwhile, selecting columns from a temporary table is similar to this unanswered SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443672/list-of-temporary-table-columns-mysql

Comment: Well, that seems somewhat dirty. I will definitely test it though. Thank you

Comment: What did you ultimately end up doing?

Comment: I reimagined the original issue and managed to fit it to info schema, eliminating temporary tables. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to know the columns in a table just do:

```
DESCRIBE `table_name`
```

Otherwise there is no "real" way to get the number of columns in a select query since other than selecting `*` you select certain columns --> so **you** will know how many columns you are selecting.

Comment: Though that is true, I can't programatically get the number of rows from `Describe` either. You've got a point I should generally know the columns though. It's just not always the case.

Comment: Prety good. It shows a line counter on the left side of the result. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find your answer here most likely: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Write a query off of that that takes a table name param and then query for columns of that table and sum that up.