# List temporary table columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created one temporary table named "table1". I am trying to list the columns of my temp table. I am not getting any values. Here is my mysql query.

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'table2';
```

Any body help me please?
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16296395/575376

Comment: Please try to google it, INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't lists temporary tables..

Comment: I upvoted this because the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html)  documentation does not mention anything about temporary tables.  The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) documentation does say, "Currently, the TABLES table does not list TEMPORARY tables." But again, that says nothing about the COLUMNS table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot get the temporary table columns using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html)

The only way which you can use is to go with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table2`

"INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" does not contains columns of temporary table.

Answer (score 6):

You can use SHOW COLUMS to achieve this.

Example Table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SalesSummary (
product_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
total_sales DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
avg_unit_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
total_units_sold INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 );
```

Command:
    SHOW COLUMNS FROM SalesSummary;

Outout:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM SalesSummary;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_name     | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| total_sales      | decimal(12,2)    | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| avg_unit_price   | decimal(7,2)     | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| total_units_sold | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

More details are in the manual Section 13.7.5.5 for MySQL 5.7. [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)

Another possibility is using SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
 mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE SalesSummary\G
 *************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: SalesSummary
 Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `SalesSummary` (
  `product_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `total_sales` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `avg_unit_price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total_units_sold` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are some more [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html).

In Mysql 5.7 there is a seperate table called INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO to achieve this.

Comment: thanks a lot, it was useful. unfortunately i can able to check answered only one.

Comment: if you create a table in session then you can access, but suppose your application create randomly temporary table as per user login, then You cant see the list of the table for all sessions.

Comment: Temporary tables in MySQL are always per session only.  [A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name.] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-temporary-table.html

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get a list of column names for *any* table.

This method will also work for TEMPORARY tables:

```
SET @columns_string = ''
;

SHOW
    COLUMNS
FROM
    `mysql`.`user`
WHERE
    @columns_string := CONCAT(`Field`, ',', @columns_string)
;

SELECT @columns_string
;
```

`@columns_string` will have a value of:

```
account_locked,password_lifetime,password_last_changed,password_expired,authentication_string,plugin,max_user_connections,max_connections,max_updates,max_questions,x509_subject,x509_issuer,ssl_cipher,ssl_type,Create_tablespace_priv,Trigger_priv,Event_priv,Create_user_priv,Alter_routine_priv,Create_routine_priv,Show_view_priv,Create_view_priv,Repl_client_priv,Repl_slave_priv,Execute_priv,Lock_tables_priv,Create_tmp_table_priv,Super_priv,Show_db_priv,Alter_priv,Index_priv,References_priv,Grant_priv,File_priv,Process_priv,Shutdown_priv,Reload_priv,Drop_priv,Create_priv,Delete_priv,Update_priv,Insert_priv,Select_priv,User,Host,
```

The problem with this solution (besides needing to parse a string) is that the `SHOW COLUMNS` command will *always* generate an (empty) resultset.

This means that you can't really use this method in a stored procedure that returns a SELECT (you will end up with more than one resultset).

Comment: This is brilliant!
Can be used as stored procedure to get columns list of any table by itself and in another stored procedure.
```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_column_list_hack`(schema_name VARCHAR(64), table_name VARCHAR(64), OUT `column_list` TEXT)
BEGIN
 SET @cs = '';

 PREPARE show_cols FROM CONCAT('SHOW COLUMNS FROM ', schema_name, '.', table_name, ' WHERE @cs := TRIM("," FROM CONCAT(@cs, ",", `Field`))');
 EXECUTE show_cols;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE show_cols;

 SET column_list = @cs;
END
```

Comment: dude, that's pure genius :D

Comment: It is working, Thanks. Additionally, it gives a result with no rows, just column names as Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra. How can we ignore or not returning this result? Any idea?