# Get hold of the columns names of a temporary table in mysql

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I need to automatically pivot the results of a query execution in mysql.
The problem is that the results are dynamic, depending on the parameters of the query I'm executing.

So to create a dynamic pivoting procedure, I need to get hold of the columns returned by the query I'm executing.

I'm saving the results into a in memory temp table.

If I do "**Describe table**" or "**Show columns from table**", I can see the columns, but cannot get hold of them programmatically, to perform the actions with the table names.

As it's a temporary table, the *information_schema.columns* does not contain any information either.

So the questions are:

**1 -** Can I get hold (in mysql) of the results of describe command

**2 -** Is there another way to get hold of the column names of a temp table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer this, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049635/222823
Thanks to sam-6174